# Proper way to loop a SQL Query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have a list that retrieves the student's grades by passing in a list of student class,

it then pulls the student grades by querying the student's name through the database. This code works fine however, when the studentList increases in size, this code gets really slow to execute,

What is the proper method for looping a list through a sql query?

```
private List<StudentClass> getStudentGrades(List<StudentClass> studentList)
{
    for (int i =0; i < studentList.Count; i++)
    {
        string sqlcommand = "SELECT StudentGrades FROM Students WHERE StudentName=@StudentName";
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", studentList[i].StudentName);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Reader())
            {
                studentList[i].StudentGrades = int.Parse(reader["StudentGrades"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return studentList;
}

public class StudentClass
{
    public string StudentName {get; set; }
    public int StudentGrades {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The reason this is slow is because it is calling a new query for every student. It would be much better to send in the list of students and make a single set based query. You might also want to take a look at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`is of no use, just *remove* it

Comment: felt the -1 was a little harsh for the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all - you're unnecessary executing your command twice. You're calling `ExecuteNonQuery` first (it will has no effect since `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't returns data, but it slows down execution since request actually being passed to SQL server and being executed). Then you're calling `ExecuteReader` from which you're actually retrieving data.

Second issue - you're executing new query for each student. So if you will have 1000 students in list - it will be 1000 queries executed.

Consider getting all data from database first, and then update your `studentList` accordingly.

Something like getting `SELECT StudentName, StudentGrades FROM Students` first, save result to some dictionary (or wherever you want) and then do your loop over `studentList`

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<StudentClass> getStudentGrades(List<StudentClass> studentList)
{
    string sqlcommand = "SELECT StudentGrades FROM Students WHERE StudentName=@StudentName";
    var conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName");
    using (conn)
    {
        conn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < studentList.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value= studentList[i].StudentName;
            studentList[i].StudentGrades = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }            
    }

    return studentList;
}
```

Note: You should retrieve the whole list in one query, it would be much much better.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out, you don't need the executenonquery.

But the bigger issue is that your SQL statement only returns one student's data at a time.  Is there another field you can use to select all students in a group at at time?  I.e., is there a "class" field or something like that, so you can do something like:

```
select studentgrades
  from students
 where class = @class
```

If not, you can still write a kind of ugly sql statement with an in clause.  So:

```
select studentgrades
  from studens
 where studentname in ('studentname1', 'studentname2', etc. )
```

Using that approach, you'd modify your code to be something like this:

```
private List<StudentClass> getStudentGrades(List<StudentClass> studentList)
{
        string studentListParam = "";
        foreach(StudentClass student in studentlist)
        {
           // blah blah stuff to only add comma if not first element
           studentListParam = studentListParam + ", '" + student.StudentName + "';
        }

        string sqlcommand = @"
SELECT StudentName, StudentGrades
  FROM Students
 WHERE StudentName in (" + studentlist + ")";
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", studentList[i].StudentName);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Reader())
            {
                StudentClass student = studentList.Where(s => s.StudentName == string.Parse(reader["StudentName"]);
                student.StudentGrades = int.Parse(reader["StudentGrades"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return studentList;
}

public class StudentClass
{
    public string StudentName {get; set; }
    public int StudentGrades {get; set; }
}
```

Obviously you'd need some null checks and various other bits of error checking to make this really production ready, but that should be a starting point.

(Also, note that this approach doesn't try to parameterize the query, so you'd lost a little bit of parse time, but's going to be orders of magnitude less than you're losing with the multiple queries.)

Comment: You're missing `StudentName` in the select. And it should be `...(" + studentListParam + ")...`, but the `studentListParam` is going to have an extra comma at the beginning.  Use `string.Join` instead.  Finally this is open to sql injection.

Comment: You shouldn't build a SQL string like this. If one of the student names has special characters in then it could cause an exception (or worse, in the case of a deliberate SQL injection).

Comment: Yes, it's open to sql injection.  Trying to cover that as well as the actual original question would have made the answer overly complicated.  Hence the "other bits of error checking to make this really production ready" comment.